# Active MQ redelievery policy seems to be not working - defined through URL configuration

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-classic

```
failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?  jms.useAsyncSend=false&jms.redeliveryPolicy.redeliveryDelay=14400000")
```

I have defined the queue url as above, setting the redelivery delay to be 4 hours.
But when the expected exception occurs, the messages are retried immediately 5 times and dequeued from the Queue. Any thoughts?

Comment: Active MQ URL configuration doesnt seems to work correctly. So I got this working by setting the delivery delay in RedeliveryPolicy configuration in JMSConnectionFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active MQ URL configuration doesnt seems to work correctly. So I got this working by setting the delivery delay in RedeliveryPolicy configuration in JMSConnectionFactory